# Why is the quantity "Geopotential" important in meteorology?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere-modelling, barometric-pressure

So far I understood, geopotential $\Phi$ is just defined by

$$\vec \nabla \phi = \vec g$$

But because g can be taken to be constant within troposphere, it is nothing but

$$\Phi(z) = g \cdot z + C$$

So it is nothing more than height z multiplied by a constant. What is the benefit of it? These relations are trivial - is there anything I have overseen?

[image]

In this image one could equally say that minimum surface pressure corresponds to minimal **height** of constant pressure layers above.